# Replace image url template with values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I get image urls from an API that looks like this:
http://www.example.com/image.jpg{?width, height}

And I wanna make a neat function in javascript that can translate that into a useable image source. This is how I've been doing stuff like this earlier, but it is not so very pretty (crude example):

```
url = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg{?width,height}";

width = 1024;
height = 768;

parsedUrl = url.replace("{?width", "?width=" + width);
parsedUrl = parsedUrl.replace(",height}", "&height=" + height);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nhxa5t02/

How would you solve this in another way?

Comment: maybe you will like this expression more `parsedUrl = url.replace('{?width,height}', () => \`?width=${width}&height=${height}\`)`

Comment: Yes indeed. Maybe I should do that before I do anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct the string, so `width` and `height` will be interpolated

```
url = `http://www.example.com/image.jpg{?${width},${height}}`
```

and perhaps put it in to a function for re-use

```
const getImageUrl = (width, height) => {
  return `http://www.example.com/image.jpg{?${width},${height}}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create such a utility function using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const assembleUrl = (width, height) => 
    `http://www.example.com/image.jpg?width=${width}&height=${height}`;
```

And use it like this:

```
const width = 1024;
const height = 768;

// outputs "http://www.example.com/image.jpg?width=1024&height=768"
const parsedUrl = assembleUrl(width, height);
```

Comment: Thank you. But then I need to parse the URL to match the one you use in your example?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Why do you need to parse the assembled URL?

Comment: Sorry. But if you look at your url it is not the same as mine.

Comment: Please take a look that at the end the URL is exactly as yours here https://jsfiddle.net/nhxa5t02/: "_?width=1024&height=768_" - the part of the URL with parameters appears to be the same. You use brackets "{}" around a part you need to replace, in template literals these brackets indicate a place where to embed an expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Modifying your solution**

```js
const width = 1024;
const height = 768;

const parsedUrl = `http://www.example.com/image.jpg{?${width},${height}}`;
```

**Reusable Function**

```js
const parsedUrl = (width = 768, height = 1024) => `http://www.example.com/image.jpg{?${width},${height}}`;
```

Benefits of 2nd approach is that there are default values if you don't specify any

E.g. `parsedUrl()` will work just fine but if you need to overwrite any of them just pass arguments accordingly. Like `parsedUrl(256, 512)`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are receiving the URL as `"http://www.example.com/image.jpg{?width,height}"`, first remove the `{?width,height}`, then add the height and width using template literals.

```
const width = 1024;
const height = 768;

const parsedUrl = `${url.replace(/{.+}/,"")}?width=${width}&height=${height}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a variable for width and height in URL itself makes sense. You can either directly replace the variables and save the parsed URL in a variable or create a method to replace those variables.

```js
const url = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg?width={width}&height={height}";

const width = 1024;
const height = 768;

const parsedUrl = url.replace("{width}", width).replace("{height}", height);

console.log(parsedUrl);
```